# Magento: How to switch the total including tax and total excluding tax on order invoice email ? Any ideas?

Tags: magento, email, invoice

Can you give some ideas or a complete solution for how to switch the total including tax and total excluding tax on order invoice email ? ... Now total excluding tax is first and total including tax second ... i want to switch them, so the first will be total including tax, and the second one total excluding tax. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can override this files to your theme and change table structure as you need

you can find out in below file

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\sales\order\invoice\items\renderer\default.phtml
```

and change as you need to change position of your total display in invoice

hope this will sure help you.